# Trane Air Handler GAT2A0C48S41SAA Create "C" Wire

Tags: hvac

Can someone please Tell me the Best way to Create a "C" Wire for a WiFi thermostat Honeywell Wi-Fi Smart Thermostat (RTH9580WF). I currently have a Trane thermostat TCONT602AF22MA. Please... Thanks Joe
I'm a retired USAF SMSgt and I'm trying to save Money.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the unit, you should find a transformer. On the secondary side of the transformer (low voltage side) you should see a red wire attached to one terminal, and blue attached to the other.  The terminal with the blue wire will also have a green with yellow strip wire, which attaches to the chassis.  The blue wire is the `C` wire.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Using a multimeter set to AC volts, you should measure about 24 volts between the red and blue wires.

Connect a wire between the blue wire terminal on the transformer, and the `C` terminal on the thermostat.  That should get you up and running.